# Play developer console - multiple closed test tracks

Tags: android, developer-console, testtrack

I have been using the default Alpha closed test track to get feedback from a helpful set of my users. Everything has worked fine. The latest apk on there is versionCode 10.

Now I've realised I want to have a subset test extra features, so I created a new test track, turned off the list on Alpha, and turned it on on the new track. I uploaded a new apk versionCode 16, and would expect those people to see an update available. I have included my own email account in that, but nothing appears. I've even uninstalled the app and reinstalled, but it offers me the Alpha track option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sorted it!

The users have to LEAVE being a tester, then rejoin. When they rejoin it will put them on the correct apk/track.